# Is the LT8500 a current source or sink on its PWM outputs?

Tags: current, integrated-circuit, linear

I am using the [LT8500](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/8500f.pdf) as an LED driver and I need to know if the leds are current sink or source.

Also if I need to have resistors in serial with the PWM outputs since the output voltage is 4V.

I've looked through the whole datasheet and I'm not finding anything at all so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the LT8500 is just a PWM generator, so the PWM outputs are totem-pole signals meant to be interfaced to either a MOSFET, or a companion device to actually drive LEDs.

Comment: Is there anyway I can use it to directly use it with LEDs?  The datasheet says it can directly drive LEDs.  Are they just being lame?

Comment: Well, sure, if the outputs can drive 3mA you would get some light out of some LEDs, but forget driving a string or getting a lot of brightness.  What I see in the datasheet is: "suitable for control applications such as driving three LT3595A LED drivers."  These are companion ICs that are meant for driving LEDs directly.

Comment: could I not just use a darlington transistor?

Comment: Yes, absolutely you could use a Darlington (with a current limiting resistor in series with your LED, and another in series with the base.)  You'd get faster switching and more headroom using a MOSFET though.

Comment: Ok! I'll see what I can do with a simple N-channel fet.  Hopefully I can find one in the SOT-23-5 package

Comment: There are plenty of N-FETs available in SOT-23. I think there are duals (common source or common drain) in SOT-23-5, not sure about singles though.

Comment: Yea, I found a double in a SC-70 package which is nice.  Just kind of a shame I'll be doubling my BOM by including those. Oh well, its the only solution for the price until the TLC5958 comes out.

Answer (score 2):

PWM outputs are signals.  It can sink or source on the order of 3mA.  (p.3 in the datasheet)

[image]

It doesn't look like it's intended for driving the LED directly.  But it can control an external power device, which sources or sinks a larger current through the LED.

[image]

(p.22 in the datasheet)